# Why the size of objects with age n+1 in current suvivor is large than objects with age n in previous suvivor?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

When trying to optimizing JVM GC flags, I added `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution` to print the object size distribution of different ages, and I found a strange phenomenon.

Intuitively, the size of objects with age (n+1) in current GC process should be smaller than the size of objects with age n in last GC process.

The objects with age 2 in second GC are those objects with age 1 in first GC. Assume that the size of live objects with age 1 in first GC is S11, and the size of live objects with age 2 in second GC is S22. Then S11 > S22, because some objects with age 1 are destroyed

But What I saw is:

```
- age   1:    5028488 bytes,    5028488 total
gc happened...
- age   2:    5030440 bytes,    7630688 total
gc happened...
- age   3:    6864328 bytes,   10406920 total
gc happened...
- age   4:   13155416 bytes,   17153720 total
gc happened...
- age   5:   11057632 bytes,   15633880 total
gc happened...
- age   6:   17349112 bytes,   22898584 total
```

As we see, its size increased. I have no idea why this happened. Following is the complete GC log:

```
2017-08-30T13:22:33.821+0800: 219271.297: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
2017-08-30T13:22:33.821+0800: 219271.297: [ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    5028488 bytes,    5028488 total
- age   2:     394616 bytes,    5423104 total
- age   3:     414024 bytes,    5837128 total
- age   4:     851040 bytes,    6688168 total
- age   5:     462728 bytes,    7150896 total
- age   6:     526064 bytes,    7676960 total
: 1343960K->9188K(1504064K), 0.0105175 secs] 5697641K->4363292K(8221504K), 0.0106539 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-08-30T13:22:33.831+0800: 219271.308: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0119211 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001500 seconds
2017-08-30T13:22:34.486+0800: 219271.963: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-08-30T13:22:34.486+0800: 219271.963: [ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    2600248 bytes,    2600248 total
- age   2:    5030440 bytes,    7630688 total
- age   3:     392760 bytes,    8023448 total
- age   4:     413704 bytes,    8437152 total
- age   5:     850888 bytes,    9288040 total
- age   6:     462488 bytes,    9750528 total
: 1346148K->11226K(1504064K), 0.0103425 secs] 5700252K->4365843K(8221504K), 0.0104998 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-08-30T13:22:34.497+0800: 219271.973: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0116511 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000986 seconds
2017-08-30T13:22:35.151+0800: 219272.627: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-08-30T13:22:35.151+0800: 219272.627: [ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    3132664 bytes,    3132664 total
- age   2:     409928 bytes,    3542592 total
- age   3:    6864328 bytes,   10406920 total
- age   4:     392304 bytes,   10799224 total
- age   5:     413120 bytes,   11212344 total
- age   6:     588304 bytes,   11800648 total
: 1348186K->12885K(1504064K), 0.0109247 secs] 5702803K->4367954K(8221504K), 0.0110585 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-08-30T13:22:35.162+0800: 219272.638: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0122836 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001519 seconds
2017-08-30T13:22:35.841+0800: 219273.318: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-08-30T13:22:35.841+0800: 219273.318: [ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    2544776 bytes,    2544776 total
- age   2:    1045056 bytes,    3589832 total
- age   3:     408472 bytes,    3998304 total
- age   4:   13155416 bytes,   17153720 total
- age   5:     392008 bytes,   17545728 total
- age   6:     412920 bytes,   17958648 total
: 1349845K->19062K(1504064K), 0.0100055 secs] 5704914K->4374704K(8221504K), 0.0101450 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-08-30T13:22:35.851+0800: 219273.328: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0113139 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001079 seconds
2017-08-30T13:22:36.260+0800: 219273.736: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0018019 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0003786 seconds
2017-08-30T13:22:36.521+0800: 219273.997: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-08-30T13:22:36.521+0800: 219273.997: [ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    2977976 bytes,    2977976 total
- age   2:     408656 bytes,    3386632 total
- age   3:     781704 bytes,    4168336 total
- age   4:     407912 bytes,    4576248 total
- age   5:   11057632 bytes,   15633880 total
- age   6:     391592 bytes,   16025472 total
: 1355810K->16950K(1504064K), 0.0107807 secs] 5711453K->4372995K(8221504K), 0.0109248 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs] 
2017-08-30T13:22:36.532+0800: 219274.008: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0121995 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001272 seconds
2017-08-30T13:22:37.214+0800: 219274.691: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-08-30T13:22:37.214+0800: 219274.691: [ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes, new threshold 6 (max 6)
- age   1:    3480256 bytes,    3480256 total
- age   2:     473344 bytes,    3953600 total
- age   3:     407336 bytes,    4360936 total
- age   4:     781080 bytes,    5142016 total
- age   5:     407456 bytes,    5549472 total
- age   6:   17349112 bytes,   22898584 total
```

Comment: Could it be, that the objects are not getting more but growing? So say, an object with a reference, which is `null` during the first collection but has changed to referencing an actual object during the next iteration?

Comment: The new objects referenced during the next iteration has their own ages

Answer (score 0):

The formula `Size(age(n+1)) < Size(age(n))` is wrong.

Use your `gc.log` above as an example, in the first gc, the `Size(age(1))` is `5028488`, but in the second gc, the `Size(age(1))` is `2600248`, which means that **the object generate more slowly than the beginning**.

So, you will see that in the second gc, the `Size(age(2)`) is `5030440`, nearly equals to the `Size(age(1))` in the first gc, which make it bigger than the the `Size(age(1))` in the second gc.

The key point is that the generate speed is **constantly changing**. So may be `Size(age(n+1)) < Size(age(n))`, or may be `Size(age(n+1)) > Size(age(n))`, it's all possible.

hope i didn't misunderstand your question.

Comment: The objects with age 2 in second GC are those objects with age 1 in first GC. Assume that the size of live objects with age 1 in first GC is S11, and the size of live objects with age 2 in second GC is S22. Then S11 > S22, because some objects with age 1 are destroyed.

Comment: The age of those objects generated between the first GC and the second GC shoud be 1, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is looking very closely at the log. Your output says `ParNew Desired survivor size 85557248 bytes` but looking at your last log, you see a combined space consumption of 22898584 bytes. This is larger than what survivor can take. So basically, your age-statistic has to reference `survivor` and `tenured` at the same time.

I would assume, you have some objects of age 2/3/4/5/6 which already got promoted to `tenured` and are not affected by the collection happening.